# Adding a page with ajax in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm stuck with my codes for 2 weeks already. I want to have a page with 2 dropdowns. The first DD will show all 'states' from my database and the second DD should be based on the 1st DD's value. I think my codes are OK but the problem is the integration with wordpress itself. Is there any codes/functions/etc needed for a page to be read as ajax?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>None</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function parseResponse(adminResponse,nList){

        var nText = adminResponse.getElementsByTagName('optionText');
        var nVal = adminResponse.getElementsByTagName('optionVal');
        nList.options.length = 1;
        for (i=0; i<nText.length; i++)
            {
             var nOption = document.createElement('option');
             nOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(nText[i].firstChild.data));
             nOption.value = nVal[i].firstChild.data;
             nList.appendChild(nOption);
            }
    }

    function update(nVal,nList,getFile){

        var adminRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest()
                             : window.ActiveXObject
                             ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                             : null;
        adminRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
             if (adminRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                 if (adminRequest.status == 200)
                    {
                     var adminResponse = adminRequest.responseXML;
                     parseResponse(adminResponse,nList);
                    }
                 else   {
                     alert('Error ' + getFile + ' --- ' + adminRequest.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        var infoStr = "?choice="+nVal;
        adminRequest.open("GET", getFile + infoStr, true);
        adminRequest.send(null);
    }

    function init(){

        var nForm = document.forms[0];
        nForm['state'].onchange = function()
            {
             if (this.value != "")
                {
                 update(this.value,nForm['city'],'<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/updateGroup.php');
                }
            }
    }

    navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', init, false) : addEventListener('load', init, false);    

</script>
<style type="text/css">

     body {background-color: #eae3c6; margin-top: 60px;}
     form {width: 430px; margin: auto;}
     fieldset {width: 410px; background-color: #f0fff0; border: 1px solid #87ceeb;}
     legend {font-family: times; font-size: 14pt; color: #00008b; background-color: #87ceeb;
         padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px ; margin-bottom:5px;}
     select {font-family: tahoma; font-size: 10pt; width: 160px; margin-left: 35px; margin-bottom: 10px;}   

</style>
</head><?php /* Template Name: Practice */
    ?>
    <body>
    <?php

        global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode GROUP BY FULLSTATE ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
           $dd .= "<option value='".$row['STATE']."'>".$row['FULLSTATE']."</option>";
        }

    ?>
        <form action="">
           <fieldset>
            <legend>Form</legend>
                <select name="state">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                    <?php echo $dd; ?>
                </select>
                <select name="city" onchange="alert(this.value)">
                    <option value=""> Make a selection </option>
                </select>
           </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

First, I pasted those codes in notepad++ and saved it as practice.php. Uploaded it to my wordpress theme directory. Typing http://www.site.com/practice.php shows 'page not found' so i went to wordpress dashboard and created a new page -> assigned the template named 'practice'. typed http://www.site.com/practice.php again and it works.

```
<?php  

    $choice = $_GET['choice'];
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' ?><options>"; 

    global $wpdb; 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM zipcode WHERE STATE = '$choice'";
    $result = @mysql_query($query);
    $num = @mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($result && $num > 0)
        {
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
               $xml .= "<optionText>" . $row['CITY'] . "</optionText><optionVal>" . $row['CITY'] . "</optionVal>";
            }
        }
    $xml .= "</options>";
    @mysql_free_result($result);
    @mysql_close();
    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo $xml; 

?>
```

Ok so next i created a page with the codes above and named it updateGroup.php. uploaded it on wordpress theme directory.
Tested my codes and...I can't get it to work!! :(
Please i need help. should i add get_header and get_footer for my reference page? or do i need to configure something in wordpress to recognize my ajax?

Comment: add require_once('../../../wp-load.php'); in your ajax page at the top after <?php .

Comment: @Pranita, that's a terrible practice as it will load WordPress **2 times**. . . . . user3391847, your code is quite confusing, you should look how to [use Ajax with WordPress properly](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Comment: *sigh* guess ajax in wordpress isn't that easy. I have to call various functions and bla bla bla in my script. What's worst is I've only googled the codes i've posted above so I can't fully rewrite it from scratch if I to add wordpress functions. Anyway, Thanks for the replies